# Making sure that a jar is not run by double clicking it

Tags: java, jar

When I create a runnable jar file it works after executing  `java -jar Test.jar` but when I make a regular jar file and execute the script the black command window opens for a second but it closes immediately.

So how can I make a jar file that I can run via `java -jar Test.jar` but not by double clicking on it?
I need to make sure that the jar / program is only called through my "officially" provided starter batch.

Comment: because its not runnable. do you have a question?

Comment: you said it yourself - `runnable` jar- can run, not runnable - can't. as simple as that

Comment: @Marged I do not want to to be run by double clicking

Comment: @Marged more details please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are basically trying to do is prevent your .jar file from being called by doubleclicking it.

As doubleclicking the jar and running it with `java -jar` is the same it is hard to differentiate / detect. But as you are already using a batch to call your program you could do something like this:

```
@echo off
java -jar foo.jar OK!
```

All you have to do then is check if this signal was given while launching your program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("OK!")) {
        System.out.println("Everything fine");
    } else {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This will make sure that you can detect how your program was launched. Perhaps it is a good idea to give the user reason why you exit the program when not called from the batch.

Please note that this does not keep "malicious" users from creating their own batch because you can't hide the signal from them.

Another approach would be to create a regular jar and specify the information that normally the manifest created for a runnable jar would do:

```
@echo off
java -cp foo.jar org.your.package.MainClass
```

But I prefer the first approach because I consider it easier and more userfriedly because you can provide information to them.

Comment: @LoveJavaTwo This aren't many downvotes. Some people attract 10+ downvotes in 5 minutes ;-) I think the problem was that you only provided 90% of the information. _You_ did know why you want to do this, but you didn't disclose this to _us_.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to put

```
if (args.length == 0)
    System.exit(0);
```

In the beginning of the

```
main(String[] args)
```

method.
Then the only way to run the program is by entering some parameters (doesn't matter what) from the command line.